# create a prepared statement errors out

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to create a prepared statement in java using a mySql Database. This isn't working, but I know it will if I hard code it. What am I missing? Can you point me in the right direction?

The goal is to insert into the db table the values from the ArrayList. I pass the table name and the arraylist to the write function. The method determines how many items there are in the arraylist and creates the preparestatement. This appears fine. Initailly, I used hardcoded values to test and it works when I do this:

```
      preparedStatement.setString(1, "100");
      preparedStatement.setString(2, "20160549");
      preparedStatement.setString(3, "11:30");
      preparedStatement.setString(4, "860232630");
      preparedStatement.setString(5, "Brenda");
      preparedStatement.setString(6, "Joy");
      preparedStatement.setString(7, "BrnMulligan@gmail.com");
      preparedStatement.setString(8, "0");
      preparedStatement.setString(9, "Coast Guard");
      preparedStatement.setString(10, "Veteran");
      preparedStatement.setString(11, "1");
     */
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
      }
```

but when I do this:

```
      String strData="";
      for(int i=1;i<fieldCount;i++){
         //fields start with 1
          System.out.println("i is: "+i);
         //array starts at 0
          int j = i-1;
          strData="\"" + dataArray.get(j) + "\"";
          System.out.println("Data is: "+strData);
          preparedStatement.setString(i,strData);
      }
```

It stops dead. There is no stack output of an error, another tab opens with this:

[output of new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnsA7.png)

[image]

I don't have the experience yet to understand what its telling me. I though including the whole method would help.

```
 public static void mySqlWrite(String tableName, ArrayList dataArray)        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
          //Lets take a look at whats comming in...
          System.out.println("The table name is : " + tableName);
          System.out.println("The dataArray is : " + dataArray.size());

          //Since we want to re-use this code for every write to the db,
          // we start manipulating the incoming data 

          int fieldCount = dataArray.size()+1;
          // we can start anywhere, so lets start with the table of the  database
          // we want to insert the values into.
          String strPrepStatement="";

          for(int i=1;i<fieldCount;i++){
              System.out.println("i is: "+i);
              //create the placeholders for the data
              strPrepStatement= strPrepStatement + "?,";
              System.out.println("Statement is: "+strPrepStatement);
          }

          //There's an extra comma, so we remove it.
                                       strPrepStatement=strPrepStatement.substring(0,strPrepStatement.length()-1);


          // Lets see if it worked.           
          System.out.println("Statement is: "+strPrepStatement);

          //Lets create the prepstatement now
          String strPrep = "insert into vms." + tableName + " values (" + strPrepStatement +
                  ")";
          System.out.println("PrepStatement is: "+strPrep);

        // This will load the MySQL driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // Setup the connection with the DB
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection(url,sqluser,sqluserpw);

          // PreparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
          preparedStatement = connect
              .prepareStatement(strPrep);
          String strData="";
          for(int i=1;i<fieldCount;i++){
              System.out.println("i is: "+i);
              int j = i-1;
              strData="\"" + dataArray.get(j) + "\"";
              System.out.println("Data is: "+strData);
              preparedStatement.setString(i,strData);
          }
     /*     
          preparedStatement.setString(1, "100");
          preparedStatement.setString(2, "20160549");
          preparedStatement.setString(3, "11:30");
          preparedStatement.setString(4, "860232630");
          preparedStatement.setString(5, "Brenda");
          preparedStatement.setString(6, "Joy");
          preparedStatement.setString(7, "BrnMulligan@gmail.com");
          preparedStatement.setString(8, "0");
          preparedStatement.setString(9, "Coast Guard");
          preparedStatement.setString(10, "Veteran");
          preparedStatement.setString(11, "1");
         */
          preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
          }

      // You need to close the resultSet
      private static void closeDB() {
        try {
          if (resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
          }

          if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
          }

          if (connect != null) {
            connect.close();
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
      }
```

Comment: *so I'm just writing stuff until it determines that there are enough characters to post this* SERIOUSLY?! Please read [ask].

Comment: ok, thanks for the replies, I will read the how to ask. This line creates the error: preparedStatement.setString(i,strData); The error is java docs opens (?) and the form opens Class File Editor, source not found. When I comment out the loop to create the preparedStatement and uncomment the hard coded portion, it works fine.

Comment: If you have an empty catch block where you call this method from, like in your `closeDB()` method, then you won't see any exception that maybe thrown. Also you say you can hardcode those values - does your input ArrayList contain those same values?

Comment: I will edit the catch statement. The hardcoded values are not the same. There is the same count. The primary key for the db is .setString(4,"860232622") so it is changed each time. You point out a possibility tho, my input data order can be diff, as I'm collecting it from another source. Let me make those changes...

Comment: What are these `\"` in your `strData="\"" + dataArray.get(j) + "\"";`? You are trying to do some kind of double quoting? I would assume you are are having some integer columns in your table, that would not work... Just let prepare do its job. Don't add quotes yourself. Adding the prepared variable as a string will add quotes already (even for integers). You are now trying to add an additional `"` and get `'"0"'` instead of `0`.

Comment: Thank You, Solarflare, Yes, I was trying to add quotes, so that my Sys.out would look identical to the hardcoding.....let me try it....